# JSON in the Url - Right or Wrong

Tags: php, json, url, url-routing

Recently I got into a discussion at work about using JSON in the api.

One argument for putting in a query string was ok, it would act as a parameter, retrieved using $_GET and decoded in the application.

index.php ? action = {JSON}

The other argument was put it as a $_POST only, the argument against it was that urls would become to long.

So what are thoughts about using JSON in url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal thought is that it is better to put it in POST, for a couple of reasons

- GET is much easier for users to manipulate.  Although POST is not
  safe either, people won't try to fiddle with it if they don't know
  how to.
- While long, complex URLs are probably more specific to an individual    (I may
  not care if they're long or not), it is beneficial in that    those
  that don't care *don't care*, but those that do care, well,    they
  care.

It is more semantic to look at things that change something on the server should always be sent via POST, and things that only change what is requested should be sent through GET.  It's not too clear from your question what the ultimate intent of the JSON is, although I think your discussion is less concrete and more abstract in that regard.

Comment: GET is much easier for users to manipulate … therefore it *should* be used so people can easily fiddle with it.

Comment: I guess that depends whether you _want_ people to fiddle with it or not.  I would say in most circumstances that you don't.

Comment: More seriously. You can't stop people from controlling what they send to you, security by obscurity is just self-delusion. You shouldn't allow pseudo-security to influence your choice of GET or POST. The main driver for that should be if the request will be [Safe / Idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1)

Comment: I totally agree, using POST doesn't increase security at all.  My point is a naive user may see the JSON in the URL and decide to fiddle with it.  Putting it in POST prevents manipulation by naive users, which is better than nothing.

Comment: Not really. You need to have input checking to make sure that the data sent by non-naïve attackers is safe, and that will work against accidental attacks too.

Comment: That checking should exist regardless, so I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  My argument is that removing it from the URL simply removes the natural tendency of curious people to mess with things.

Comment: I'm saying that since that checking has to exist regardless, it *doesn't matter* if people mess with things.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the reason for using JSON is that you want to be able to encapsulate some arbitrary amount of data (list of things, objects containing variable data, etc).  Since you are very limited in how many characters you can use in a URL you will only be able to send very limited amounts of data if you choose to transmit it via a GET request.  You will also need to encode/decode the JSON if it appears as part of the URL, which complicates things a bit.  If you aren't sure how much data will be coming in this way you really need to use POST.